# Removing output cache with HttpResponce.RemoveOutputCacheItem doesn't work on share hosting. Web forms

Tags: asp.net, caching, webforms

i have an application that cache pages with output cache directive of  asp.net.
When i insert update or delete somthing from the control panel i want to reset the output cache.
Locally my algorithm works great.
When i run it on share host, cache doesn't clear.

my algorithm is very straight forward : 
In global.asax i init a list with all the pages that i use output cache.

```
OutputCacheHelper.Directories.Add(OutputCacheHelper.AllPagesKey, new List<string>() {
         "/Default.aspx",
       "/pages/DisplayContactForm.aspx",
       "/pages/PhotosGallery.aspx",
       "/pages/Schedule.aspx",
       "/pages/Shows.aspx",
       "/pages/cms/DisplayCategory.aspx",
       "/pages/cms/DisplayCategoryAlternative.aspx",
       "/pages/cms/DisplayFrontPage.aspx",
       "/pages/cms/ViewAirstaff.aspx",
       "/pages/cms/ViewArticle.aspx",
       "/pages/cms/ViewShow.aspx"
});
```

Then whenever i insert/update/delete data from the database i use the above algorithm :

```
        foreach (string directory in Directories[AllPagesKey])
        {

            HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(directory);
        }
```

I don't know why this don't work on shared hosting.
Please help.
Thank you and sorry for my english.

---

### EDIT

Sorry for the delay.
I was on a business trip.

I figure it out...
Not as i want but i can apply only output cache.
(because Azure is not available)
I add a dependance on a file and then when i want to clear the cache, i just chage the content.
Is it ok?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shared hosting is a single server or a server farm (like AZURE)?
Cache is a server-level, so in a multi-instance context, clearing cache on an istance doesn't effect cache on other servers.

EDIT
In multi-server context you can:
  -use **shared cache** (AZURE provides it but it costs money)
  -**create a system that manages cache** (ie use a DB table to store last update time for each object, so that any server before look into cache knoes if it has to be resetted)
  -**avoid using cache**

Comment: Wow...right. It is on server farm...
What could i do about this?

Comment: I think what @Emanuele means is that if your app is running on multiple servers at the same time (load balanced), that clearing the cache on one won't clear it on the others.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application deployed as a web app, or a web site? If you're running in a virtual directory, I believe you need to include the virtual directory's path in the calls to `RemoveOutputCacheItem()`.

Having said that, have you considered using SQL Server query notifications (Service Broker) to do this instead? ASP.NET makes it pretty easy. For example, see `SqlDependency`, `SqlCacheDependency` and `Response.AddCacheItemDependency()`.